# Google Chrome doesn't return to UTF-8 after moving to another page

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, encoding, utf-8

I noticed strange behaviour for google chrome.
I have web application based on  java spring-mvc framework.
In head tag `<meta charset="utf-8">`is set.

For each page response headers return  `Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8`
In IE 8,9,10,11 and FF **if user changes encoding in browser's settings to KOI8-R** and then goes to another page inside domain - browser encoding will be **automatically returned to UTF-8.**

BUT in google chrome in same case **KOI8-R will be present** even if we go to other pages inside domain.

Is it expected behaviour for Chrome? Maybe it is some kind of bug?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome doesn't like to use UTF-8 by default so you have to do:

1. Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
2. Select "Tools"
3. Select "Encoding".
4. Pick one "Unicode (UTF-8)" from the menu of encodings

To make the client do this by default you would probably have to write some script but I'm afraid I can't help you out there.